# xUnit results pretty-printing in *nix shell

Tags: linux, software-testing, xml

Every test command prints its results differently, but many of them support saving the result to **xUnit XML files.** To get nice, instantly recognisable test result output from various test runs I'm looking for a tool to **pretty-print such files in a *nix shell.**

*Ideally* the tool

- *colour codes* output depending on the test result,
- runs in *Bash* on recent Linux and
- is easy to install on *Fedora* Linux (either using Yum or as a single file with no external dependencies).